# Building along with Project Dependencies in Ant

Tags: ant, build, dependencies

I have a Java project that is dependent on other Java projects that are siblings and there is a chain of dependencies. Each individual project has a build script written in Ant. For clarity find below a sample of the same.

1. `EARProject` depends on `WebProject` and `EJBProject`: The `war` file that is generated by the `WebProject` build and `jar` file that is generated by the `EJBProject` are needed to build the `EARProject`.
2. `WebProject` depends on `ComponentOneProject`: The `jar` file that is generated by the `ComponentOneProject` build is needed to build `WebProject`.
3. `EJBProject` depends on `ComponentTwoProject`: The `jar` file that is generated by the `ComponentTwoProject` build is needed to build `EJBProject`.

So, when I build the `EARProject` build, if the dependent `war` and `jar` have not been built yet, then it should kick-off the `WebProject` build and `EJBProject` build and if the `ComponentOneProject` is yet to be built, the build of `ComponentOneProject` needs to be kicked-off and so on.

Can someone suggest a clean method by which we can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facing the same problem we at our company wrote a custom Groovy script that explores the full dependency tree ant generates the Ant build scripts based on all the .project, .classpath, .settings/* files. This wasn't as difficult as it might seem as first. This way we can build our products without (My)Eclipse on a clean CVS+JDK+Groovy virtual machine. Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes I like this route in identifying the dependencies. I am also proceeding in the same direction with the difference that I am writing new Ant tasks in Java to interpret the `.project` and `.classpath` files. The actual problem that I have is enforcing a build of component on which the current build is dependent on. As an example, from above the build for `EARProject` should kick off the build for `WebProject` and `EJBProject` if they are not build yet.